# Trying to install ubuntu on VMware Player

Tags: 14.04, vmware, 32-bit, vmware-player

I'm trying to create virtual machine with Ubuntu. I have VMware Player in version 3.1.6 build-744570.

When I'm trying to install 64 bit version, I'm getting error:
[image]
when I tried install 32bit version error become more complex:
[image]
Can somebody explain to me, what this error means (especially second one) and how I can fix it.

Comment: Try using the latest vmware player, 3.1 is pretty old.